# CSS long text-shadow method not working

Tags: html, css, text, shadow

So I've been using this method for making long text shadows:
(http://codepen.io/SteamPanda/pen/QNxvpY)

```
.text {
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-shadow: 
  1px 1px orange, 
  2px 2px orange, 
  3px 3px orange, 
  4px 4px orange, 
  5px 5px orange,
  6px 6px orange, 
  7px 7px orange,
  8px 8px orange,
  9px 9px orange,
  10px 10px orange,
  11px 11px orange, 
  12px 12px orange, 
  13px 13px orange, 
  14px 14px orange, 
  15px 15px orange,
  16px 16px orange, 
  17px 17px orange,
  18px 18px orange,
  19px 19px orange,
  20px 20px orange,
}
```

This seems like it should work, but the orange shadow stopped showing up after about ten shadows. Is there some shadow limit? Too much code? I'm  open to alternative methods, but I'd like to stick with plain CSS3.

Comment: Seems to work fine (on Chrome) if I remove that last comma.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Case closed